# CCSprite still responds to touch even after it is removed from parent and cleaned up

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a custom subclass of CCSprite and in it I am doing this:

`[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:-1 swallowsTouches:YES];`

during the sprite's custom initialization.

Very interestingly, even when I do this later, from the main scene class that controls it:

`[customSprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];`

The sprite still responds to this method, in its class:

`-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

very curious indeed!

I did not initially have this, but I added it to the custom sprite class and it made no difference:

```
-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Any idea what is happening here?

UPDATE: not sure this is relevant but I'm wondering if `removeFromParentAndCleanup` works on a sprite that is added to sprite batch, as my sprite is indeed part of a `CCSpriteBatchNode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CCTouchDispatcher` will retain your sprite. You need to call `[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];` when removing the sprite.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
- (void) onEnter{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    [super onEnter];
}

- (void) onExit{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
    [super onExit];
}
```